# Get highest value by group in R dplyr - handling ties

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like so:

```
state_id person_id salary
1        1         100000
1        2         100000
1        3         34560
2        4         67800
2        5         54670
3        6         67000
3        7         55000
3        8         55000
4        9         123450
```

I want to get a single person for each state with the highest salary. If there are two people with the same salary and it is the highest salary in the state - I want to just choose any one of them. How can I do this in R - dplyr?

Expected output:

```
state_id person_id salary
1        2         100000
2        4         67800
3        6         67000
4        9         123450
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `slice_max` here.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(state_id) %>% slice_max(salary, with_ties = F)

# A tibble: 4 × 3
# Groups:   state_id [4]
  state_id person_id salary
     <int>     <int>  <int>
1        1         1 100000
2        2         4  67800
3        3         6  67000
4        4         9 123450
```